# Using the Crystal Reports Picture function with a Parameter as the format

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to create a generic report that has a data field which needs to be displayed with a user defined format. The format is defined and stored in a configuration table, which I retrieve and pass into the report as a parameter.

I am not having any luck.  When I try the formula below (and several other variations), the report prints with the format displayed first, and then the data appended to it, without the format applied.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
WhileReadingRecords;
Local StringVar lsParcelNumber := {vRealEstateTaxBill.Parcel};

lsParcelNumber := Picture(lsParcelNumber, {?lsParcelFormat});

lsParcelNumber;
```

Comment: First of all, remove the last semi-colon in line four. It should be  "lsParcelNumber". And why are you assigning values to the same variable twice?

Comment: @campagnolo_1 - I have tried various solutions.  In the post, I put the most recent version.  Before making the post, I tried to simply format the string with the parameter as you have posted in your answer, but I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing too much about your report, I would give this a shot:

```
StringVar IsParcelNumber := Picture({vRealEstateTaxBill.Parcel}, {?lsParcelFormat});
IsParcelNumber
```

I don't know what your `{?lsParcelFormat}` looks like, but I would suggest if the above formula doesn't work to "spell" out the picture format (i.e. "(xxx) xxx-xxxx"). And you know that the `WhileReadingRecords` will apply the formula while reading the records. So if at all, you should try `WhilePrintingRecords`, but I would leave it out alltogether.

Comment: I did try this solution before making the post, I get the same results.  I am trying to avoid hard coding the picture format, so that the report can be used by several users and string be displayed according to their custom format.  That way I do not have to customize the report for every customer using the software.  I will keep playing with it and see what I get.

Comment: Have you tried simply "Picture({vRealEstateTaxBill.Parcel}, {?lsParcelFormat})"?

Comment: I just found the problem.  The format was "00-000-AA-AAA0-AA-AAAAA" and not "xx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xx-xxxxx".  So now I have to replace all the characters with an "x", but keep the mask!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: A-ha! Glad it was a "simple" fix!